How to expose EKS application on 2 VPCs
I have an EKS cluster running in one VPC with corp network traffic only. I have my application exposed with an ALB (using AWS Load Balancer Controller w/ k8s Service + Ingress) using TLS. I have another VPC with public access. The 2 VPCs have a Peering Connection.
What are the best practices for creating an LB inside the public VPC so it points to the application on the private VPC? The public LB should have one DNS domain, while the private LB should have another.
Looking for general advice. Until now I have a very bad solution where I have an ALB on the public VPC and it points directly to the IP of the Kubernetes Service inside the private VPC.
Thank you for your help!

I'd probably look at using privatelink.

Thanks for the tip. I've ended up configuring the k8s service as an NLB and having its static IPs as targets for the ALB in the other VPC. Indeed privatelink was something I considered but given that I need to have it working for one other VPC only, I thought this is a simpler solution.

Good that you've found a solution. Please put your solution into the answer box so it can be marked as solved, so others people don't have to come in and try to help solve a resolved problem.

overall architecture
Attached you can find the overall architecture. As described in my initial comment on my question, I've ended up using an NLB (provided by AWS Load Balancer Controller) with n static private IPs (1 IP / subnet). After that, I've configured the ALB in the public VPC to point to the NLB.
Each ALB terminates ingress with their own TLS certificate, so there's no local https traffic.
Note: a VPC peering connection is crucial for this setup. If you don't want to/can't create a VPC peering connection, take Tim's advice and look into Privatelink.
